# How to show $a^nb^{2n} = (ab^2)^n$ inductively.

Tags: induction

The solution hint given is to prove inductively, by noting that : 
$$ a^{n+1}b^{2n+2} = ab^2(a^nb^{2n}) = ab^2(a^nb^{3n} -1)$$

But, am unable to use the hint given, as am unable to see how $$ab^2(a^nb^{2n}) = ab^2(a^nb^{3n} -1)$$

I can only solve using the conventional inductive approach, as below:

Taking the base step, for $n=1$:$$ab^2 = ab^2$$
Taking the assumption that the hypothesis (to be proved) is true for the case $n=k$, get :$$a^kb^{2k} = (ab^2)^k,$$
Now, the final step to show that it is true for $n = k+1$:$$a^{k+1}b^{2k+2} = (ab^2)^{k+1} \,\,\,\,\,: (i)$$

For this take the l.h.s.: $a^{k+1}b^{2k+2} = a^k\cdot a\cdot b^{2k}\cdot b^2= (ab^2)^kab^2=$ desired r.h.s.

Comment: $x^{nm} = (x^n)^m$ is enough to prove the result

Comment: @Jack plus $x^ny^n=(xy)^n$

Comment: Oh and $x^n y^n = (xy)^n$

Comment: Setting $a=b=1$ shows the hint is in fact false!

Comment: The first part of the hint, $a^{n+1}b^{2n+2}=ab^2(a^nb^{2n}$, is just what you did. The second part of the hint, $ab^2(a^nb^{2n})=ab^2(a^nb^{3n}-1)$, is simply wrong